# How to clear the IOExceptionE error in j2me midlet when connect http and send sms vias?

Tags: java, java-me, sms, midp

I am working on j2me Mobile application part. I have to send message using http connection and sms format (using sms gateway).

When I am trying to do this, the `java.io.IOException: Resource limit exceeded for file handles` is throwing in my console.

How to avoid this? This is my connectivity code:

```
public boolean sendViaHTTP(String message)
{

    System.out.println("enter HTTP Via");
HttpConnection httpConn = null;

String url = "http://xxx.com/test.php";

System.out.println("URL="+url);
InputStream is = null;
OutputStream os = null;
try 
{
    // Open an HTTP Connection object
    httpConn = (HttpConnection)Connector.open(url);
    // Setup HTTP Request to POST
    httpConn.setRequestMethod(HttpConnection.POST);
    httpConn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent",
    "Profile/MIDP-2.0 Confirguration/CLDC-2.0");
    httpConn.setRequestProperty("Accept_Language","en-US");
    //Content-Type is must to pass parameters in POST Request
    httpConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    String value = System.getProperty("com.nokia.network.access");
    os = httpConn.openOutputStream();
    String params;
    params = "message=" + message;
    os.write(params.getBytes());// input writes in server side

    // Read Response from the Server
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    is = httpConn.openDataInputStream();
    int chr;
    while ((chr = is.read()) != -1)
    sb.append((char) chr);

    Response = sb.toString();

    //switchDisplayable("", getForm());

    //System.out.println("REsponse="+Response);
}
catch(IOException ex)
{
    System.out.println(ex);
    return false;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    System.out.println(ex);
    return false;
} 
finally 
{
    try 
    {
        if(is!= null)
        is.close();
        if(os != null)
        os.close();
        if(httpConn != null)
            httpConn.close();
    } 
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        System.out.println(ex);
    }
}
return true;

}
```

Comment: You should build the "User-Agent" dinamically with System.getProperty("microedition.profiles") and System.getProperty("microedition.configuration")

Answer (score 3):

That exception is (most likely) happening because somewhere in your application you are not closing your streams after you have finished reading from / writing to them.

To illustrate, if this statement

```
   if (is != null) is.close();
```

throws an exception (e.g. an `IOException`), then the remaining statements in the `finally` block won't be executed.  That could leak a file descriptor.

The problem might also be in another part of the code entirely, but the exception message *clearly* points to a problem with your application using too many file descriptors, and the most likely cause of that is a resource leak.

Comment: i have checked in my application,all the streams are closed.

Comment: @cheliyan - Let me say this again.  The exception is SAYING that you have too many files open at the same time.  You might think that you have closed them, but in fact you haven't.

Comment: thanks for providing lot of help, i understand your concept and implemented the same, finally it works fine.i really great-full to u.